# Is it possible to stop the constructor loading the index function?

Tags: php, codeigniter

when i check the under construction checkbox then the site goes offline and the constructor needs to load the construction_view. But how can i stop the constructor loading the index function when under_construction = 1? I tried exit; die() return; but it still loads the index function.

```
function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('breadcrumb');
        $this->load->model('Site_model');
        $this->footer['footer'] = $this->Site_model->get_allCategories();
        $this->load->vars($this->footer);

        $construction = $this->Site_model->construction();
        if ($construction->under_construction == 1) {
            $this->load->view('construction_view');
            exit; // die(); // return;
        }
    }
function index(){
    $this->load->model('Site_model');
    $data = array();
    $title['title'] = 'Nordia - Home';
    $data['categorieInfo'] = $this->Site_model->get_allCategories();
    $this->load->view('head_view',$title);
    $this->load->view('nav_view');
    $this->load->view('banner_view');
    $this->load->view('categories_view',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer_view',$this->footer);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not just put that `$construction` item in `index()` since it's being called already?

Comment: I would make a "construction" action and reroute every request to that.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `$construction` item to `index()`, should alleviate your issue.  Load one or the other.